# Returning empty rows in GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-warehouse

I have a query to retrieve a total number of events per day between two dates.

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(startTime, '%Y%m%d') as day,
  COUNT(0) as numEvents
FROM events
WHERE
  (startTime BETWEEN 20140105000000 AND 20140112235900)
GROUP BY
  day;
```

This return a list like

```
day      | numEvents
---------+----------
20140105 | 45
20140107 | 79
20140108 | 12
20140109 | 56
```

Notice that there are missing days in the result since there are no events in the events table for those days. Is there any way to return 0 values for those days, resulting in:

```
day      | numEvents
---------+----------
20140105 | 45
20140106 | 0
20140107 | 79
20140108 | 12
20140109 | 56
20140110 | 0
20140111 | 0
20140112 | 0
```

Comment: A few solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310839/sql-group-by-including-empty-rows

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few solutions on SO:

- [How do I include empty rows in a single GROUP BY DAY(date_field) SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592983/how-do-i-include-empty-rows-in-a-single-group-by-daydate-field-sql-query)
- [generate empty rows even if empty between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575271/generate-empty-rows-even-if-empty-between-2-dates)
- [SQL Group By including empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310839/sql-group-by-including-empty-rows)
- [MySQL GROUP BY and Fill Empty Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252460/mysql-group-by-and-fill-empty-rows)
- [Summarise by week, even for empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895752/summarise-by-week-even-for-empty-rows)

[One solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262296/1085891) is to you another table that contains all possible/relevant dates. One implementation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262803/1085891

> This is typically done in data warehouses by having a date dimension
>   that has a list of all possible dates. You do an OUTER JOIN to the
>   date dimension and COALESCE the null values to 0.

If run often, it would be more efficient to store the dates. However, for a quick report you could generate the dates you need and join the output to the table you are searching against.

- [t-sql get all dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946121/t-sql-get-all-dates-between-2-dates)
- [SQL Server: How to select all days in a date range even if no data exists for some days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899829/sql-server-how-to-select-all-days-in-a-date-range-even-if-no-data-exists-for-so)
- [Get all dates in date range in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140308/get-all-dates-in-date-range-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(startTime, '%Y%m%d') as day, COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(startTime, '%Y%m%d'))
FROM  events 
WHERE
(startTime BETWEEN 20140105000000 AND 20140112235900)
GROUP BY day;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will able to do it if `startTime` is a foreign_key to another table which have values for every date. This is tipical on multidimensional models of data-warehouses, where you have a date/time dimension and them include all days.

In that case, I think the solution provided by [Vigens Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2118383/vignesh-kumar) would work:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(startTime, '%Y%m%d') as day, COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(startTime, '%Y%m%d'))
FROM  events 
WHERE
(startTime BETWEEN 20140105000000 AND 20140112235900)
GROUP BY day;
```